# Haskell - Passing each element of array with another parameter to function

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell, and have been trying to solve this for a while.

I have a function:

```
sumNodeError :: Node -> Layer -> Double
sumNodeError node childLayer = foldl (+) 0 (listProduct (weights node) (errors childLayer))

calculateNodeError :: Node -> Layer -> Double
calculateNodeError node childLayer = (sumNodeError node childLayer) * (value node) * (1.0 - (value node))

-- problem is in this function
calculateErrors :: Layer -> Layer -> Layer
calculateErrors layer childLayer = Layer (nodes layer)
                                         (map calculateNodeError (nodes layer) childLayer ) -- problem, need to map each of the nodes in the layer, and the childLayer to calculateNodeError
                                         (teacherSignals layer)
                                         (learningRate layer)
```

I am needing to pass each `(nodes layer)` and the `childLayer` to function `calculateNodeError`

The rest of the code (which isn't much) can be found here if you need: https://github.com/kennycason/haskell_nn/

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go

```
(map (\n -> calculateNodeError n childLayer) (nodes layer) )
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked, I wasn't even aware that I could compose the function like that! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution.

```
map ((flip calculateNodeError) childLayer) (nodes layer)
```